# Java regex replace n amount of whitespaces where only n exist and not n+-1 or n+-1

Tags: java, regex

Hi this is really troubling me, and I just cant figure out the regex.

I would like a regex that could replace n amount of consecutive whitespaces with '♥', but only if there i exactly n amount of whitespace and not more or not less.

Pseudo code:

```
String myReplaceFunction(String text, String replaceThis, String withThis, int countOfConcecutive);

String originalString ="    This is  a   very    short    text    .     ";
String regexMagicString = myReplaceFunction(" ", "♥", 4); 
System.out.println(regexMagicString); // "♥This is  a   very♥short♥text♥.     "
```

Comment: Show your regex attempt, and its output.

Comment: you can create your pattern to include the number you want. something like `"\\s{"+nbSpace+"}"` but I can't say more without a [mcve]. PS : You forgot the `originalString` parameter in the function call.

Comment: [`(?<! ) {4}(?! )`](https://regex101.com/r/v5vfLT/1)?

Comment: Can you share the code for `myReplaceFunction()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/v5vfLT/2)

```
(?<! ) {4}(?! )
```

Replacement: `♥`

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/BPwdSW)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final String string = "    This is  a   very    short    text    .     ";
        final String replace = " ";
        final String subst = "♥";

        String result = myReplaceFunction(string, replace, subst, 4);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static String myReplaceFunction(String text, String replaceThis, String withThis, int countOfConsecutive) {
        replaceThis = Pattern.quote(replaceThis);

        final String regex = String.format("(?<!%1$s)%1$s{%2$s}(?!%1$s)", replaceThis, countOfConsecutive);

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(withThis);

        return "Substitution result: " + result;
    }
}
```

---

### Results

**Note**: The input contains 5 spaces after the `.` that don't get replaced.

#### Input

```
    This is  a   very    short    text    .
```

#### Output

```
♥This is  a   very♥short♥text♥.
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?<! )` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes is not a space character
- `{4}` Match the space character exactly 4 times
- `(?! )` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not a space character

Comment: This is very detailed. You did not have to write up an example for me, but the "Explanation" part is really what I needed.
I have tried with all kinds of combinations, but after hours I just had to accept that I did not understand regex well enough.
As you explain, what I needed was the lookbehind and lookahead. I did not understand this functionality and how to use it until now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @SimonKaae you're very welcome. I changed the **Usage** code so that it more closely resembles the method you're trying to create. It also properly quotes the regex string (not the number since it's an `int`) so that you don't get weird things happen (i.e. if you tried to replace `.` with something). I like to provide detailed responses because [tag:regex] answers tend to lack information/explanations. It may also help future readers if they are looking for similar solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work (no look-behind or look-ahead needed):

```
/(^|\S)\s{4}(\S|$)/
```

Just remember to replace it by `$1♥$2`.

Answer (score 0):

As this whitespace probably excludes the line breaks `\s` is not possible.

```
s = s.replace("(?<![ \t])[ \t]{13}(?![ \t])", "♥");
```

- For whitespace: `[ \t]`.
- Negative look-behind: `(?<![ \t])` - zero-width.
- Negative look-ahead: `(?![ \t])`

*I did not test it.*